# xamarin android jar binding error - Class does not implement interface method

Tags: c#, xamarin, jar, binding, xamarin.android

I have a some problem with xamarin binding project.

I got error message below from vs2017 when I was build Android binding project.

**Class does not implement interface method**

of course, I have found some tips to solve this problem through editing Metadata.xml

but, It is not working. because I have no experience about this.

so. please, I want you to watch my source attached file.

I would upload tow files.
one of them is binding project made by vs2017 including jar.
and then anther one is original jar sdk to bind into my android project.

binding project download link : http://cloud-wr-sg1.acronis.com/links/8E2127FA6223CFC1DA19AE89FB393BAF

original jar file download link : 
http://cloud-wr-sg1.acronis.com/links/705ADB4D99254F8490FD3B1D1AACEA34

I need help. I'm in emergency.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any update?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the official documents: [Java Bindings Metadata](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/) and [Troubleshooting Bindings](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/). For your scenario, you can add a additional file in your binding library for example like this:

```
namespace Com.Skp.Tmap
{
    partial class TMapView
    {
        void DraggingAnimateThread.IDraggingCallback.Zoom(float p0, bool p1)
        {
        }

        void DraggingAnimateThread.IDraggingCallback.Rotate(float p0)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where Do I have to write down your sample in my project?
It just would include in project as a cs file?

Comment: @BongLae, there is a folder in binding lib project named `Additions`, you can create a class named `TMapView` there then override it like the sample I provided, it just solved the issue of building your binding lib, it doesn't do anything useful actually in `Zoom(float p0, bool p1)` and `Rotate(float p0)` methods, if you want to do something, you will need to refer to the source code of your .jar and then fill the code here in each method.

Comment: @BongLae, if you find this answer helpful, could you please mark this answer?